# Unmarshalling with Jackson "The Json input stream must start with an array of Json objects"

Tags: json, jackson, spring-batch, unmarshalling

I'm getting an error when unmarshalling files that only contain a single JSON object: "IllegalStateException: The Json input stream must start with an array of Json objects"
I can't find any workaround and I don't understand why it has to be so.

```
@Bean
public ItemReader<JsonHar> reader(@Value("file:${json.resources.path}/*.json") Resource[] resources) {
    log.info("Processing JSON resources: {}", Arrays.toString(resources));
    JsonItemReader<JsonHar> delegate = new JsonItemReaderBuilder<JsonHar>()
            .jsonObjectReader(new JacksonJsonObjectReader<>(JsonHar.class))
            .resource(resources[0])  //FIXME had to force this, but fails anyway because the file is "{...}" and not "[...]"
            .name("jsonItemReader")
            .build();
    MultiResourceItemReader<JsonHar> reader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
    reader.setDelegate(delegate);
    reader.setResources(resources);
    return reader;
}
```

I need a way to unmarshall single object files, what's the point in forcing arrays (which I won't have in my use case)??

Comment: NB: JacksonJsonObjectReader and GsonJsonObjectReader work the same way, apparently

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand why it has to be so.

The `JsonItemReader` is designed to read [an array of objects](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/json/JsonItemReader.html) because batch processing is usually about handling data sources with a lot of items, not a single item.

> I can't find any workaround

[`JsonObjectReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/json/JsonObjectReader.html) is what you are looking for: You can implement it to read a single json object and use it with the `JsonItemReader` (either at construction time or using the setter). This is not a workaround but a strategy interface designed for specific use cases like yours.

Comment: Thanks. But I can't use the object reader as a delegate for MultiResourceItemReader, can I ? It doesn't implement ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream

Comment: No, the delegate of `MultiResourceItemReader` should still be a `JsonItemReader`. You just need to use a custom `JsonObjectReader` with the `JsonItemReader` instead of `JacksonJsonObjectReader`. Visually, this would be: `MultiResourceItemReader` -- delegates to --> `JsonItemReader` -- uses --> your custom `JsonObjectReader`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok got it! Sorry for being slow. As it is JsonItemReader javadoc that says that the reading structure is a list, I thought that the object (no plural) reader was just handling single values

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not ideal @thomas-escolan. As @mahmoud-ben-hassine pointed, ideal would be to code a custom reader.

In case some new SOF users stumble on this question, I leave here a [code example on how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63711038/reading-very-complex-json-using-spring-batch/68743716#answer-68743716)

Answer (score 0):

Though this may not be ideal, this is how I handled the situation:

```
@Bean
public ItemReader<JsonHar> reader(@Value("file:${json.resources.path}/*.json") Resource[] resources) {
    log.info("Processing JSON resources: {}", Arrays.toString(resources));
    JsonItemReader<JsonHar> delegate = new JsonItemReaderBuilder<JsonHar>()
            .jsonObjectReader(new JacksonJsonObjectReader<>(JsonHar.class))
            .resource(resources[0]) //DEBUG had to force this because of NPE...
            .name("jsonItemReader")
            .build();
    MultiResourceItemReader<JsonHar> reader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
    reader.setDelegate(delegate);
    reader.setResources(Arrays.stream(resources)
            .map(WrappedResource::new) // forcing the bride to look good enough
            .toArray(Resource[]::new));
    return reader;
}
@RequiredArgsConstructor
static class WrappedResource implements Resource {
    @Delegate(excludes = InputStreamSource.class)
    private final Resource resource;
    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        log.info("Wrapping resource: {}", resource.getFilename());
        InputStream in = resource.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, UTF_8));
        String wrap = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining())
                .replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\xFF]", "");  // strips off all non-ASCII characters
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(("[" + wrap + "]").getBytes(UTF_8));
    }
}
```