# Reading Very Complex JSON using Spring Batch

Tags: json, jackson, spring-batch, unmarshalling

My objective is to read a very complex JSON using Spring Batch. Below is the sample JSON.

```
{
  "order-info" : {
  "order-number" : "Test-Order-1"
  "order-items" : [
  {
   "item-id" : "4144769310"
   "categories" : [
    "ABCD",
    "DEF"
   ],
   "item_imag" : "http:// "
   "attributes: {
      "color" : "red"

   },
   "dimensions" : {

   },
   "vendor" : "abcd",

   },
   {
    "item-id" : "88888",

    "categories" : [
    "ABCD",
    "DEF"
   ],
   .......
```

I understand that I would need to create a Custom ItemReader to parse this JSON.
Kindly provide me some pointers. I am really clueless.

I am now not using CustomItemReader. I am using Java POJOs. My JsonItemReader is as per below:

```
@Bean
 public JsonItemReader<Trade> jsonItemReader() {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

       JacksonJsonObjectReader<Trade> jsonObjectReader =
                new JacksonJsonObjectReader<>(Trade.class);

       jsonObjectReader.setMapper(objectMapper);

        return new JsonItemReaderBuilder<Trade>()
                .jsonObjectReader(jsonObjectReader)
                .resource(new ClassPathResource("search_data_1.json"))
                .name("tradeJsonItemReader")
                .build();
}
```

The exception which I now get is :

***java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Json input stream must start with an array of Json objects***

From similar posts in this forum I understand that I need to use JsonObjectReader. "*You can implement it to read a single json object and use it with the JsonItemReader (either at construction time or using the setter)*".

***How can I do this either @ construction time or using setter? Please share some code snippet for the same.***

***The delegate of MultiResourceItemReader should still be a JsonItemReader. You just need to use a custom JsonObjectReader with the JsonItemReader instead of JacksonJsonObjectReader. Visually, this would be: MultiResourceItemReader -- delegates to --> JsonItemReader -- uses --> your custom JsonObjectReader.***

Could you please share a code snippet for the above?

Comment: which JSON fragment corresponds to an item in your case? Do you have a class representing an item? How would you do that outside of a Spring Batch job?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine: I have changed my strategy... I am not using CustomItemReader. I am now using POJOs. I now do have a class representing an item. Now I am getting a very weired but basic error which says - "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Json input stream must start with an array of Json objects". I had seen in some other post you had given that - "You just need to use a custom JsonObjectReader with the JsonItemReader instead of JacksonJsonObjectReader". Please could you give an example for the same. I am modifying my post as well.

Comment: The JsonItemReader provided by Spring Batch expects the json input to be an array of items, see its [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/json/JsonItemReader.html). If your input is not an array, you need a custom reader. Unfortunately, I do not have an example for that.

Answer (score 1):

JacksonJsonItemReader is meant to parse from a root node that is already and array node, so it expects your json to start with '['.

If you desire to parse a complex object - in this case, one that have many parent nodes/properties before it gets to the array - you should write a reader. It is really simple to do it and you can follow JacksonJsonObjectReader's structure. Here follows and example of a generic reader for complex object with respective unit tests.

**The unit test**

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;

import com.example.batch_experiment.dataset.Dataset;
import com.example.batch_experiment.dataset.GenericJsonObjectReader;
import com.example.batch_experiment.json.InvalidArrayNodeException;
import com.example.batch_experiment.json.UnreachableNodeException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@RunWith(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class GenericJsonObjectReaderTest {

GenericJsonObjectReader<Dataset> reader;

@Before
public void setUp() {       
    reader = new GenericJsonObjectReader<Dataset>(Dataset.class, "results");
}

@Test
public void shouldRead_ResultAsRootNode() throws Exception {
    reader.open(new ByteArrayResource("{\"result\":{\"results\":[{\"id\":\"a\"}]}}".getBytes()) {});
    Assert.assertTrue(reader.getDatasetNode().isArray());
    Assert.assertFalse(reader.getDatasetNode().isEmpty());
}

@Test
public void shouldIgnoreUnknownProperty() throws Exception {
    String jsonStr = "{\"result\":{\"results\":[{\"id\":\"a\", \"aDifferrentProperty\":0}]}}";
    reader.open(new ByteArrayResource(jsonStr.getBytes()) {});
    Assert.assertTrue(reader.getDatasetNode().isArray());
    Assert.assertFalse(reader.getDatasetNode().isEmpty());
}

@Test
public void shouldIgnoreNullWithoutQuotes() throws Exception {
    String jsonStr = "{\"result\":{\"results\":[{\"id\":\"a\",\"name\":null}]}}";
    try {
        reader.open(new ByteArrayResource(jsonStr.getBytes()) {});
        Assert.assertTrue(reader.getDatasetNode().isArray());
        Assert.assertFalse(reader.getDatasetNode().isEmpty());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Test
public void shouldThrowException_OnNullNode() throws Exception {
    boolean exceptionThrown = false;
    try {           
        reader.open(new ByteArrayResource("{}".getBytes()) {});
    } catch (UnreachableNodeException e) {
        exceptionThrown = true;
    }
    Assert.assertTrue(exceptionThrown);
}

@Test
public void shouldThrowException_OnNotArrayNode() throws Exception {
    boolean exceptionThrown = false;
    try {           
        reader.open(new ByteArrayResource("{\"result\":{\"results\":{}}}".getBytes()) {});
    } catch (InvalidArrayNodeException e) {
        exceptionThrown = true;
    }
    Assert.assertTrue(exceptionThrown);
}

@Test
public void shouldReadObjectValue() {
    try {
        reader.setJsonParser(new ObjectMapper().createParser("{\"id\":\"a\"}"));
        Dataset dataset = reader.read();
        Assert.assertNotNull(dataset);
        Assert.assertEquals("a", dataset.getId());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

**And the reader:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ParseException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.json.JsonObjectReader;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

import com.example.batch_experiment.json.InvalidArrayNodeException;
import com.example.batch_experiment.json.UnreachableNodeException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;

/*
 * This class follows the structure and functions similar to JacksonJsonObjectReader, with 
 * the difference that it expects a object as root node, instead of an array.
 */
public class GenericJsonObjectReader<T> implements JsonObjectReader<T>{

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GenericJsonObjectReader.class.getName());

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
private JsonParser jsonParser;
private InputStream inputStream;

private ArrayNode targetNode;
private Class<T> targetType;
private String targetPath;

public GenericJsonObjectReader(Class<T> targetType, String targetPath) {
    super();
    this.targetType = targetType;
    this.targetPath = targetPath;
}

public JsonParser getJsonParser() {
    return jsonParser;
}

public void setJsonParser(JsonParser jsonParser) {
    this.jsonParser = jsonParser;
}

public ArrayNode getDatasetNode() {
    return targetNode;
}

/*
 * JsonObjectReader interface has an empty default method and must be implemented in this case to set 
 * the mapper and the parser
 */
@Override
public void open(Resource resource) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Opening json object reader");
    this.inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
    JsonNode jsonNode = this.mapper.readTree(this.inputStream).findPath(targetPath);
    if (!jsonNode.isMissingNode()) {
        this.jsonParser = startArrayParser(jsonNode);
        logger.info("Reader open with parser reference: " + this.jsonParser);
        this.targetNode = (ArrayNode) jsonNode; // for testing purposes
    } else {
        logger.severe("Couldn't read target node " + this.targetPath);
        throw new UnreachableNodeException();
    }
}


@Override
public T read() throws Exception {
    try {
        if (this.jsonParser.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            T result = this.mapper.readValue(this.jsonParser, this.targetType);
            logger.info("Object read: " + result.hashCode());
            return result;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ParseException("Unable to read next JSON object", e);
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Creates a new parser from an array node
 */
private JsonParser startArrayParser(JsonNode jsonArrayNode) throws IOException {
    JsonParser jsonParser = this.mapper.getFactory().createParser(jsonArrayNode.toString());
    if (jsonParser.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
        return jsonParser;
    } else {
        throw new InvalidArrayNodeException();
    }
}

@Override
public void close() throws Exception {
    this.inputStream.close();
    this.jsonParser.close();
}

}
```